# How to improve simple SQL query by using where exists statement?

Tags: sql

Could you please help me out on improving simple query below.
Based on a last modified date (ODS_CHANGE_DATE), I set a 'ODS_CHANGE_FLAG' to 'Y' if it was modified in the last two months (done in previous query not shown here).

Then I want to set a RELOAD_INDICATOR flag to 'Y' for all records that were created in those months (based on CREATION_DATE). This way I can send all records of those months where at least 1 record was modified in the past two months.

The query below does the trick but I believe it can be optimised using a where exist statement but I am not familiar with it and I can not get it to work for the example below. Would you be willing to help me out so I can do it in one statement without using temp table?

Thanks!

```
use ODS 
update ODS_DCF_OUTPUT set reload_indicator = 'N' 

drop table #dcf_output_changed 
select concat(DATEPART(year, creation_date),DATEPART(month, creation_date)) as RELOAD_MONTH_CODES 
into #dcf_output_changed 
from ODS_DCF_OUTPUT 
where ODS_CHANGE_FLAG = 'Y'

update ODS_DCF_OUTPUT 
set ODS_DCF_OUTPUT.reload_indicator = 'Y' 
FROM ODS_DCF_OUTPUT as a 
inner join #dcf_output_changed as b on b.RELOAD_MONTH_CODES = concat(DATEPART(year, a.CREATION_DATE),DATEPART(month, a.CREATION_DATE))
```

Comment: Tag the dbms used, you have product specific SQL there.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your query could be simplified without the temporary table - as long as 'ODS_CHANGE_FLAG' is set to 'Y' in another query - as follows:

```
update ODS_DCF_OUTPUT set reload_indicator = 'N' ;

UPDATE ODS_DCF_OUTPUT
SET a.reload_indicator = 'Y' 
FROM ODS_DCF_OUTPUT a
WHERE
concat(DATEPART(year, a.CREATION_DATE),DATEPART(month, a.CREATION_DATE))
IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT
     concat(DATEPART(year, b.CREATION_DATE),DATEPART(month, b.CREATION_DATE))
     FROM ODS_DCF_OUTPUT b WHERE b.ODS_CHANGE_FLAG = 'Y'
   )
```

**Make sure to take backup before messing with your data.**

Comment: Problem with that is that ODS_CHANGE_FLAG is set for particular records within a month but I need to set RELOAD_INDICATOR flag for ALL records of those months that have ODS_CHANGE_FLAG = 'Y' for at least one record.

Comment: Hi Shadi - I changed "a.reload_indicator" to "reload_indicator" and then it worked. Thanks a lot!! Topic can be closed.

Comment: Glad it worked! you could close the topic by marking my post as an answer.